# Choosing random number where probability is random in Python

Tags: python, numpy, probability

While I can find decent information on how to generate numbers based on probabilities for picking each number with [numpy.random.choice](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) e.g.:

```
np.random.choice(5, 3, p=[0.1, 0, 0.3, 0.6, 0])
```

which picks 0 with probability p =.1, 1 with p = 0, 2 with p = .3, 3 with p = .6 and 4 with p = 0.

What I would like to know is, what function is there that will vary the probabilities? So for example, one time I might have the probability distribution above and the next maybe p=[0.25, .1, 0.18, 0.2, .27]). So I would like to generate probability distributions on the fly. Is there a python python library that does this?

What I am wanting to do is to generate arrays, each of length n with numbers from some probability distribution, such as above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One good option is the **Dirichlet distribution**: samples from this distribution lie in a `K`-dimensional simplex aka a *multinomial distribution*.

Naturally there's a convenient numpy function for generating as many such random distributions as you'd like:

```
# 10 length-4 probability distributions:
np.random.dirichlet((1,1,1,3),size = 10)
```

And these would get fed to the `p=` argument in your `np.random.choice` call.

You can consult [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution) for more info about how the tuple parameter affects the sampled multinomial distributions.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there's no inbuilt way to do this. You can do roulette wheel selection which should accomplish what you want.

The basic idea is simple:

```
def roulette(weights):
    total = sum(weights)
    mark = random.random() * total
    runner = 0
    for index, val in enumerate(weights):
        runner += val
        if runner >= mark:
            return index
```

You can read more at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitness_proportionate_selection